# RegEx Groovy for assertion

Tags: regex, groovy

Can someone help for regular expression for the following  (only alphanumeric upper and lower case with - after 12 characters) i need to use in in my groovy assertion.

```
7AYNEHFjEee4-AJiXJP2jg
```

Comment: do you want to match the whole string you provided? Start to end of line? Just the 12 char and `-` ? Be a bit more specific

Comment: start to end and "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
assert '7AYNEHFjEee4-AJiXJP2jg' =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{9}$/
```

Comment: thank you daggett, it worked.